# How to Specify Use of NVIDIA CUDA nvcc 4.1 instead of 4.0?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia

VS2010 still compiles with nvcc 4.0 after installing and the GPU Computing SDK 4.1 and the CUDA Toolkit 4.1 available [NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 4.1 (64bit)](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-41). Note that I did elect to install the Visual Studio integration feature from the CUDA toolkit installer. Then I manually perform the steps outlined in

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.1\extras\visual_studio_integration
```

I tried uninstalling 4.1 and then uninstalling 4.0, followed by re-installing 4.1. Oddly, even after the 4.0 uninstall reported success the directory

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0
```

continues to exist in parallel with

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.1
```

Note that I previously had good success using the 4.0 toolkit. (Actually, since it isn't completely uninstalled, I still compile with 4.0 without error.)

I tried downloading and installing the 32-bit CUDA Toolkit 4.1 and GPU Computing SDK 4.1, but they complain that a version is already installed. I checked and the 64-bit toolkit includes both 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs and stub libraries.

I have read the release notes, the [Getting Started Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Getting_Started_Windows.pdf), MSBuildExtensions.README.txt nad NvCudaRules.README.txt. I've done a recursive grep in the VC directory looking for nvcc, only finding the build rules that I added manually per the README files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed [NSight](http://developer.nvidia.com/content/parallel-nsight-21-released)?  It's meant for additional profiling and debugging, but also further integrates CUDA with Visual Studio.  Once it's installed you can select the Build Customizations on your project (Right click on project name -> Build Customizations), and check CUDA 4.1.

Comment: Right clicking on a project, selecting Build Customizations and then choosing CUDA 4.1(.targets, .props) did the trick. NSight was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the environment variables to point to 4.1?

See control panel->system->advanced->environment vars

Comment: I should have mentioned that all environment variables (CUDA_PATH, CUDA_INC_PATH, etc.) are updated to point to the 4.1 installation.